# Opera and IE8 100% Height with bottom padding BUG

Tags: html, css, height, opera

I want the pink and blue boxes to have the same height (400px), which isn't working in Opera only. The height get dragged by bottom padding, which looks like a bug to me. Could you anyone help?

**Update 1** - Just checked it in IE8 and it doesn't work either, so the prob is re-scope to IE + Opera.

**Update 2** - padding-bottom changed to 50px to make issue clearer. The version of Opera I'm using is 11.62.

Html (watch pink and blue boxes height):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <div style="display: table; width: 400px; height: 100px; background-color: wheat;">
                    <div style="display: table-cell; background-color: Green; padding-bottom: 50px; height: 100%;">
                        <div style="height: 100%; background-color: pink;">Inner</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <div style="display: table; width: 400px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On my machine both Opera12 and IE9 render these almost pixel-for-pixel the same - the only difference I can detect (in an automated screenshot compare) is a subtle colour shift.  Perhaps you should post screenshots to show what you're seeing?

Comment: You should also perhaps confirm which versions of which browsers you are testing with...  You say "Opera only" but you don't say which browsers it's behaving differently in.

Comment: @Dan Puzey I have got IE8, not IE9.

Comment: @Scott Simpson of course they do, why wouldn't they?

Comment: @user1514042: Post screenshots!  Or try an up-to-date version of Opera - this may have been a known and fixed issue.

Comment: screenshot won't help ya mate if you can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user1514042  -- Opera is a fine browser. However, I have never had a client request for Opera support nor have I seen any significant Opera use for any site I have worked on.

Comment: agreed, but I just wanted to check what's involved in getting in working first. canuse.com isn't very fond of this browser too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed by applying `box-sizing: border-box`.

here's the class:

```
.bb
{
     box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /*Firefox 1-3*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari */
}
```